# css width of a changable background

Tags: php, html, css

I'm creating a button that changes the background but I kinda got stuck.
I got far enough that I have the main functionallity but the background is not fullscreen. I have no clue how to get it back to fullscreen.

```
<html <?php echo "STYLE='background: url(".$back.") no-repeat center center fixed; width: 100%;'";?> >
```

and some css in the html

```
html {
    background: url(../pic/back2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='pic/back2.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='pic/back2.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement background-size property.

```
background-size:100% auto;
```

Comment: also remove the background-position property.

Answer (score 0):

Background size is changed using attribute `background-size` so in your case you are changing HTML property width , not the background.

Comment: alright, that explains it. I Added background-size: 100%; to the html tag and now it works thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<div id="background">
<img src="<?php echo $yourimage ;?>" class="stretch" alt="" />
</div>
```

then add this css

```
#background {
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
position: fixed; 
left: 0px; 
top: 0px; 
z-index: -999; /* Ensure div tag stays behind content; -999 might work, too. */
}

.stretch {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use Javascript?

Something like:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function background() {
        document.getElementsByTagName('html').url == "http://www.newurl.com/";
        };
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="background()"></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because I'm using cookies to save the preffered color settings. also I don't know alot about javascript.. This seemed easier

Comment: ahhhh okay, well that should work fine, I do not know enough PHP to help in this case then, sorry!